I uninstalled Postgresql 16, why is it still showing up in services?
I went to "add/remove programs" and uninstalled PostgreSQL 16.
I have PostgreSQL 15 installed on the machine.
When I go to services, I still see "postgresql-x64-16-PostgreSQL Server 16". Why is this? How do I remove this from services?

If it's anything like the way Apache2 on Windows handles services, it might be that the service was created semi-manually and the (un)installer just doesn't keep track of it, or that it considers the service as configuration rather than part of the program (and configuration is generally not auto-removed), as the service entry itself may have admin-customized parameters, service account name/password, etc.
To remove it: Copy the "Service name:" from the service's "Properties:" dialog, then use sc or Remove-Service to delete it.
Remove-Service "postgresql-whatever"

sc.exe delete "postgresql-whatever"

(Note: If you're using PowerShell, you really need to write it as sc.exe, not as sc.)
